# Problem using wscanf in c for wide characters

Tags: c, unicode

I am trying to enter 3 characters, one of which is å. Here is the code:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <io.h>     // _setmode
#include <fcntl.h>  // _O_U16TEXT
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#define SIZE 4

void set_locale_mode() {
   #ifdef _MSC_VER
   // Unicode UTF-16, little endian byte order (BMP of ISO 10646)
   const char *CP_UTF_16LE = ".1200";

   setlocale(LC_ALL, CP_UTF_16LE);
   _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
   #else
      setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   #endif
}


int main(void) {

   set_locale_mode(); 
   wchar_t myString[SIZE];
   wchar_t testChar=0x00E5;

   wprintf(L"Your test character is %lc\n", testChar);
   printf("Now, enter 3 characters: ");
   wscanf(L"%ls", myString);
   wprintf(L"Your input is %ls\n", myString);

   return 0;
}
```

However when I enter for example blå I get this output:

```
You test character is å
Now, enter 3 characters: blå 
Your input is bl┼
```

Why does not å get printed correctly after I use wscanf?

I am on windows.

Comment: "I am on windows" --> the issue is a compiler and shell one more than an OS one.  What compiler(s) are you using?  Visual Studio?

Comment: Compiler is MinGW 32 bit and yes I use VScode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want input to be using `_O_U16TEXT` too, add that to the `set_locale_mode` function.

I also suggest not mixing "wide" output with narrow, like `wprintf` and `printf`.

```c
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)
// perhaps there is already a macro for this, but I don't know of one:
#define ON_WINDOWS
#endif

#ifdef ON_WINDOWS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <io.h>     // _setmode
#include <fcntl.h>  // _O_U16TEXT

// just in case mingw doesn't define it after all:
#ifndef _O_U16TEXT
#define _O_U16TEXT (0x20000)
#endif
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#define SIZE 4

void set_locale_mode() {
#ifdef ON_WINDOWS
    // Unicode UTF-16, little endian byte order (BMP of ISO 10646)
    const char* CP_UTF_16LE = ".1200";

    setlocale(LC_ALL, CP_UTF_16LE);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);                // <- Added
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
#else
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
#endif
}


int main(void) {
    set_locale_mode();

    wchar_t myString[SIZE];
    wchar_t testChar = u'\u00E5'; // shows intent clearer than 0x00E5

    wprintf(L"Your test character is %lc\n", testChar);
    wprintf(L"Now, enter 3 characters: ");              // <- Use wprintf here
    wscanf(L"%3ls", myString); // <- limit to 3 since SIZE is 4
    wprintf(L"Your input is %ls\n", myString);
}
```

Comment: I believe you forgot to declare myString, but that was easy to fix. However,  the output is still the same as before.

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson Oups! It was lost while editing. Hmm, strange. I created a new project in VS2022, changed the name of the source code file to end with `.c` and selected `C17` standard and it prints both `å` and the entered `blå` - which it didn't do before I added the `_setmode` line for `stdin`. I can even go "all-in Swede" and enter `åäö` which shows up correctly.

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson I just tried running it from a plain CMD.EXE prompt (just in case it was the VS environment that made it work somehow) and it works fine from the prompt too. Tried with 3 random Chineese characters too. Looks good: `...
Your input is 丒且丗`

Comment: What does it mean to "select C17 standard"? How can I make sure I use it as well?

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson I just noticed that you use `mingw`, so I think the `#ifdef`s needs to be expanded. In `mingw` you select it with the compiler option `-std=c17` (I think, I don't have mingw).  The problem is most probably that `_MSC_VER` is not defined in `mingw` and I'm not sure if the MSVC functions I've used actually work in `mingw`.

Try changing `_MSC_VER`  to `__MINGW32__` as a test

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson VS2022's MSVC. If you just change `_MSC_VER` to `__MINGW32__` everywhere in my program, do you get compilation errors? (I guess you will)

Comment: I changed that, and I also changed '_0_U16TEXT' to just '0_TEXT' because it told me to, and now I myString works, but not testChar.

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson Ok, I doubt `O_TEXT` is going to work. It's a very different value (`0x4000`). Try manually defining the proper one: `#define _O_U16TEXT (0x20000)` and use that.

Comment: It works! Thank you. I will look in to it in more detail later. Btw, how did you manage to enter Chineese characters as input?

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson Lovely! You're welcome! I'll update the answer with more details. I searched for `chinese unicode` and copied three letters from whatever it was that popped up :-)

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson I've now made the mingw adaptions as I've understood what they need to be.

Answer (score 2):

Code runs into **undefined behavior** (UB) as it attempts to write using a different *orientation*.

> Each stream has an *orientation*. After a stream is associated with an external file, but before any operations are performed on it, the stream is unoriented. Once a wide character input/output function has been applied to an unoriented stream, the stream becomes a wide-oriented stream. Similarly, once a byte input/output function has been applied to an unoriented stream, the stream becomes a byte-oriented stream. Only a call to the `freopen` function or the `fwide` function can otherwise alter the orientation of a stream.  (A successful call to `freopen` removes any orientation.)
> Byte input/output functions shall not be applied to a wide-oriented stream and wide character input/output functions shall not be applied to a byte-oriented stream. ...
> C23dr § 7.23.2 4-5

Use the same orientation as well suggested by [@Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76575541/2410359) or remove the orientation.

```
wprintf(L"Your test character is %lc\n", testChar);
freopen(NULL, "w", stdout);
printf("Now, enter 3 characters: ");
freopen(NULL, "w", stdout);
wprintf(L"...");
```